# Text files open with pdf reader instead of Sublime

Tags: python, text, mime-types, sublime-text

I have Ubuntu 16.04. For some reason, the way text files were opened changed a few days ago. Before, all of them opened with Sublime. Now, they open with a pdf reader. Text files have "Python File (no console)" as Type. What's the problem? I can't really remember which was the extension of the text files before, as I never paid attention to this. So can't tell if the change is due to the new file type or the application linked to such file type.

I had a look at `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` but it's almost empty. The file `defaults.list` has:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=sublime_text.desktop
```

which suggests to me the problem is the Python File extension. I haven't tried to change the extension of the files, as I don't know that's the problem (nor how to do it).

Any ideas?

Comment: unixy OSes don't usually care much about file extension afaik.  I'd think python files would also have a text/plain mime type, and I think you're onto something looking at mime types.  Maybe something at the system level

Comment: Try [How do I set the default program?](https://askubuntu.com/q/90214) Check your `mimeapps.list` afterwards. I guess you were missing `text/x-python=sublime_text.desktop`